# hide resuls in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

so i basicly in my terminal write like this :

```
$ espeak "my text"
```

and i get output this:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

so i was wondering is it posible to hide this or do some thing ? 
PS already tried with `program &> /dev/null`

i know it's not much info but forgive me i'm still learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
espeak "my text" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: yes it works thank you wery much!! and if it is not to hard can you explain what exacly 2>&1 this end means(or why it is nesesary)